# Polygon triangulation

Tags: visual-c++, polygon, decomposition

I am working on nesting of sheet metal parts and am implementing Minkowski Sums to find No Fit Polygons for nesting. The problem is I can give only convex sets as input to the code which calculates Minkowski sums for me. Hence I need to break a concave polygon, with holes into Convex sets. I am open to triangulation also, but I am looking for a working code on VC++ (6.0). I am slightly running short on time as my whole code is ready and just waiting for input in the form of convex sets.

I would really appreciate if somebody with prior experience can help me in this. I have gone through other posts but did not find anything matching to this. I am a student of mechanical engineering and really dun have much idea about computer languages. All I can handle is compiling a code on VC++ and incorporate it with my existing code.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to OpenGL, you can take advantage of GLU's tessellation.  You don't have to actually use OpenGL to use the tessellator, but I leave that as an exercise to the reader.